# Converting string to date returning the day before

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a date in a string with this format "2017-03-14" (yyyy-MM-dd) and i am trying to convert it into a string with this format "Tuesday, March 14, 2017".

This is my code:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-03-14")
```

Now if i print the value of "date", i get this:

```
2017-03-13 22:00:00 +0000
```

This is just the day before. Why is that ?

EDIT:

I need to compare date before formatting it.

```
var newDateString : String = ""

let date2 = Date()

let comp = date2.compare(date!)

if comp.rawValue == 0 {
    newDateString = "TONIGHT"
} else {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy"
    newDateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It's always the same issue, I guess that you have a 2h differences from GMT.

Answer (score 3):

The desired Format should be:

> EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy

All you have to do is to add after your code the following code snippet:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"
let string = dateFormatter.string(from: date!) // "Tuesday, March 14, 2017"
```

*Remark:*

I'd like to suggest to do *optional binding* for declaring the `date`, as follows:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-03-14") {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy"
    let string = dateFormatter.string(from: date) // "Tuesday, March 14, 2017"
}
```

Comment: Look at my update please, i need to compare date too. Thank you so much for your response

Comment: If i do as you said, the result would be correct, which is good. But before turning it into a string with this format "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy" again, i need to compare it to the actual date. So it won't work because the actual date is "2017-03-14" and the "date" is "2017-03-13"

Comment: So, if I got it right, you want to check if the date is today to show "tonight", otherwise it should show the formatted date, right?

Comment: This is it exactly

Comment: Just to make sure that I will answer your question, when comparing the tow dates, if you are interested in the *day*, you don't care about the hours/minutes, right? I.E "Mar 14, 2017, 12:00 AM" should be equals to "Mar 14, 2017, 03:04 PM"...

Comment: Yes i don't care .. they just appear and i don't know how would i remove them.

Answer (score 3):

Your confusion is based on a misunderstanding of what Time and Date are. Evidently, you are currently located in a time zone that is 2 hours ahead of UTC (Coordinated Universal Time), previously known as Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).

When you ask the OS for a Date object converted from "2017-03-14" you get a date/time reference of Midnight the morning of 2017-03-14 ***in your time zone*** which is, correctly, 10:00 pm (22:00) then night before in UTC.

When you ask the OS for a Date object for *now* with `Date()` you get a date/time reference of ***now*** in your time zone, which will be two hours earlier in UTC.

To accurately evaluate your date string to say "is *now* earlier than 'tonight of 2017-03-14'" you will probably want to convert from "2017-03-14 23:59" (or 11:59 pm, or perhaps prior to the start of tonight's event of  8:00 pm, etc).

This will do your original comparison, but would work better as a function (although I'm not sure how you want to use it)...

```
var newDateString : String = ""

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

// set tonightDate to 1 minute before midnight, tonight, in local time
if let tonightDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-03-14 23:59") {

    // set nowDate to current local time
    let nowDate = Date()

    let comp = nowDate.compare(tonightDate)

    if comp.rawValue <= 0 {
        newDateString = "TONIGHT"
    } else {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy"
        newDateString = dateFormatter.string(from: tonightDate)
    }

}

print(newDateString)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is calculated time based on UTC so you are getting day before.You can get proper format using below code:

```
  func chageDateFormat(date:String) -> String{
  let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

  guard let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date) else {
    assert(false, "No date from string")
    return ""
  }
  print(date)
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, dd MMMM, yyyy"
  let result = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
  return result
}

let resultFormateDate = chageDateFormat("2017-03-14")
```

For comparison you also need to convert `Date()` to proper format.Both date must be in same format.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let date = NSDate()
let strdate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)

let resultFormateDate2 = chageDateFormat(strdate)
```

Now you can compare two strings

```
if resultFormateDate == resultFormateDate2{
 print("True")
}
```

Comment: This won't work for the comparison, i guess you never saw the updated question.