# SwiftDate string parsing returned 1 day less result

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftdate

I'm trying to parse a date string into a `Date` class. I'm using SwiftDate for this. But when I tried to parse it, it returned 1 day less than the value in the string. Here are some examples:

```
let birthString = "1996-10-08"
self.birthday = Date(birthString, format: "yyyy-MM-dd", region: Region.current) 
//Result: self.birthday = 1996-10-07 17:00:00 UTC 

let expiredString = "2019-09-30"
self.membershipExpiredDate = Date(expiredString, format: "yyyy-MM-dd", region: Region.current) 
//Result: self.membershipExpiredDate = 2019-09-29 17:00:00 UTC
```

How do I fix this error? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to date returning the day before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42786812/converting-string-to-date-returning-the-day-before)

Comment: Your code works just fine.

Comment: @rmaddy Ah yeah it does. Even though the value in the debugger said it was the day before, but when I printed it it is correct. Okay, I get it now. I think it's like what the page that Rakesha Shastri said, it's because of the timezone difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SwiftDate** uses regions, and you are setting the region to `Region.current`. The date is correct and you can check that using the `.timeIntervalSince1970` property. What happens is that when you print the date (which is actually just a TimeInterval, aka Double, a *specific point in time, independent of any calendar or time zone*), it's printing its [**description**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1779759-description) property, with the default time zone `UTC` (You can see it in your output `17:00:00 UTC`).

To print a date using your current locale, use [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/1780034-description) instance method:

```
print(date.description(with: Locale.current))
```